# Replace bibtex or latex {\dg} string command in java

Tags: java, latex, bibtex

I want to write a parser for a bibtex file. In my bibtex-file there is a string  `booktitle = {Wohnen - Pflege - Teilhabe {\dq}Besser leben durch Technik{\dq}}` . Anyway, I am using JUnit-Tests and a method which should detect and replace `{\dg}` to `'` or `"`. Unfortunately I am not able to write the corresponding java code, for example my following code did not detect the substring?

```
inproceedingsCitation1 += " booktitle = {Wohnen - Pflege - Teilhabe {\\dq}Besser leben durch Technik{\\dq}},\n";
```

Corresponding part of my replace-Method:

```
String afterDg = "";
CharSequence targetDg = "{\\dg}";
CharSequence replacementDg = "\"";
afterDg = afterAe.replace(targetDg, replacementDg);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression should solve your problem:

`String afterDg = afterAe.replaceAll("\\{\\\\dq\\}", "\"");`

For more details according to regular expressions, have a look at [Vogellas Java Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).